# DateTime in following format: 2016-01-13T11:11:11Z

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm trying to convert my DateTime to the following format:

ex.:

```
2016-01-13T11:11:11Z
```

But ToString("u") gives     `2016-01-13 11:11:11Z`

I need the letter `T` also between date and time. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Just use custom format in ToString()

Comment: See webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply the T directly in the format like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ"));
```

This will give you the T and Z you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the space with a T:

```
date.ToString("u").Replace(' ','T');
```