# How can I get the value of a date into a string in the format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ for CosmosDB?

Tags: c#, datetime, azure-cosmosdb

The CosmosDB database I am using suggests I store DateTime in a string.

[Working with Dates in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/working-with-dates)

So I am trying to do this:

```
string DateAndTime = DateTime.Now.ToString()
```

but it's not giving me the correct format. Is there a method to do this and to convert it to this exact format:  YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ  ?

Comment: What client are you using?

Comment: duplicates:[DateTime in following format: 2016-01-13T11:11:11Z](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34925479/995714), [date format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1728404/995714), [How can I format DateTime to web UTC format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1820915/995714), [C# DateTime to “YYYYMMDDHHMMSS” format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3025361/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given a DateTime object, how do I get an ISO 8601 date in string format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-an-iso-8601-date-in-string-format)

Comment: I've added the `azure-cosmosdb` tag since this question relates to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not already using the [`DocumentClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/cosmosdb?view=azure-dotnet), you could use this to interface with your collection.

Using the `DocumentClient` means that you can define your document types as you wish, without having to manually convert fields to string. For example, you could use the following type to create/query documents out of the collection:

```
public class CosmosDocument
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

}
```

The `DocumentClient` will then serialize/deserialize/model-bind the data, including `DateTime` values for you.

The serialization is [configurable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet) if you need to make any changes to the default settings.

**EDIT**

As noted in the comments, [CosmosClient](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3) is the newer version that provides the same functionality described above.

Comment: ... or even better now: ```CosmosClient``` [v3 documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3)

Comment: Cheers @Martin, I've updated my answer to include the newer version.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings), you should use something like that

```cs
string DateAndTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.sssz");
```

It will give you the following string `2020-04-04T11:19:06.06+3`

`yyyy` means four-digit year (`YYYY` format doesn't exist), `dd` represents the day of the month (from 01 to 31). `z` is used for offset between your local time zone and UTC

The capital `Z` literal in string indicates that datetime is in UTC format (according to ISO 8601 standard). To get it literally in a result string you may use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now` with `Z` literal or [`K`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#KSpecifier) specifier at the end

```cs
string DateAndTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.sssK");
```

It gives you `2020-04-04T08:49:22.22Z` (current datetime in UTC format). `K` specifier will add `Z` literal for UTC dates and offset (in `zzz` format) for local dates